# The second verb "BE" can be omitted after "AND"?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, conjunction-reduction, coordination-of-unlikes

Can a second "BE" verb be omitted after "AND"?

For example:

> This book **IS** good and **IS** composed of three chapters.

Can the second "IS" be omitted?

Comment: Great question, no one even noticed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can. It is correct to say this, because the same verb applies to both adjectives, and works either way.

If you said 'the book is beautiful and gold' it sounds better than 'the book is beautiful and is gold', and I think the same applies in this sentence; the omitted 'is' sounds better

Comment: "sounds better" - that is personal preference. That needs to be mentioned in your answer. The answer up until "works either way" was great. But to say omitting "is" makes it sound better is not correct. It may sound better with the "is" to many people. Its a matter of style and preference. It is perfectly reasonable to say it does not sound good - but do tell "to me".

Comment: Wow, way to wake a post from 2017??

Comment: My deepest apologies, I was bored. I was looking into "ellipsis" and came across this. Also, I hadn't notice this was from 2017.